# Please explain why lottery wins can be used as an instrumental variable

Tags: regression, instrumental-variables

I'm reading a research article on the use of **instrumental variable** and **lottery wins** as a common example. The topic is using regression to investigate the impact of non-market outcomes on life satisfaction. It is commonly used in well-being valuation research.

I kind of understand the use of instrumental variable to tackle endogeneity, that is, the interaction between independent variable and error term.

But I don't understand why and (1) how to use another variable to assure exogeneity and randomization, in my case, lottery wins instead of income, and (2) the rationale behind. The amount and frequency of lottery wins is different from income. What's more, we can still report the impact of income on life satisfaction. I get stuck of this for long. Very much grateful if you can help.

This is one of the explanation paragraph that may help you get into context:
[image]
[image]

Source: Measuring the Social Impact of Community Investment: The Methodology Paper - by Daniel Fujiwara

Comment: Form what you are saying that they made research on how money influences happiness, so what? What this has to do with statistics?

Comment: 1. It involves the use of instrumental variable.
2. The result is done by regression.

I get stuck by the mechanism........

Comment: What mechanism? From your description they are using ordinary linear regression - what is not clear in here?

Comment: My question is: why can lottery wins replace income as independent variable? And how lottery wins can solve the problem of randomized trial?

Comment: Because winning the lottery gives you a lot of money and because winning is random (at least, for people who buy the same number of tickets)